# Rails Spree Extension doesn't show instance in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, class-eval

The default Spree Commerce has "Categories" and "Brand" taxonomies. I have generated an extension that creates a custom testing page where the taxonomies are displayed, but in reverse order. This is only for practicing purposes.

The custom testing page "/testing" seems to be routing correctly and using the view `testing.html.erb`, but I can not load the taxonomies instance defined in the method. It gives me an `undefined method each for nil:NilClass`.

Note: I'm working in the extension only, not in the spree app.

> spree_custom_extension/controllers/spree/home_controller_extension.rb

```
module Spree
  HomeController.class_eval do
    def testing
      @taxonomies = Spree::Taxonomy.includes(root: :children).reverse_order
    end
  end
end
```

> spree_custom_extension/views/spree/home/testing.html.erb

```
<% @taxonomies.each do |taxonomy| %>
  <%= taxonomy.name %><br>
<% end %>
```

> spree_custom_extension/config/routes.rb

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
  get '/testing' => 'home#testing'
end
```

Comment: Have you tried not using class_eval and just monkey-patching the class? I.E., change HomeController.class_eval do to class HomeController

Comment: Yes, that way it works, but I'm only practicing that's why I'm investigating it. What I've noticed is that HomeController.class_eval only works when it's file is called home_controller_decorator.rb, like in Spree Tutorial https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/extensions_tutorial.html#adding-a-controller-action-to-homecontroller

Comment: I'm starting to think that _decorator is a convention for naming controllers in Spree extensions. But I'm not sure.

Comment: _decorator used to extend/enhance the model/controller functionality. this would work as exactly as a generic model/controller. the purpose of this is to extend the model/controller functionality without changing/touching the core logic.